# Background image for 3d model Renderable

Tags: android, augmented-reality, arcore, android-augmented-reality

In my application i need to develop full screen background image for 3d modelRenderable object added to sceneView.

I did it by way described in the topic: https://github.com/google-ar/sceneform-android-sdk/issues/332

Created ViewRenderable object from imageView resource and added it to sceneView containg my 3d modelRenderable. Used setLocalPosition(0,0,-2) for anchorNode with image, so it is shown as background for 3d model, but the size of image changed and it is not full screen now. I tried to use setLocalScale/setWorldScale with hardcoded values.

This solves the issue only for particular device (if i run the app on different device - the image will be not full screen). Looking for solution adaptive for all devices.